# ajax call not working properly in php

Tags: php, ajax

in the below code I am passing `ipdno` as a param, and then I am getting the response from server for that this is my code.

**php**

```
$('#print').click(function(){
            var ipdNo = $('#hid_ipd_id').val();         
            var param = "ipdNo="+ipdNo;
            alert("Param: "+param);
            $.ajax({
                url: "ipd_bill_print.php", //The url where the server req would we made.
                async: true,
                type: "POST", //The type which you want to use: GET/POST
                data: param, //The variables which are going.
                dataType: "html",
                success: function(data){
                    //alert("Result: "+data+"\nRefreshing page... ");   
                    if(data=='success'){
                        alert("Record updated succcessfully!");
                        location.reload(true);
                    }else{
                        alert("Record could not be updated!");
                    }
                }
            });

        });
```

In this code I want to indicate the success when there are some rows, otherwise it should indicate the failure.

**ipd_bill_print.php**

```
<?php
    require_once("db/include.php");

    $ipd_no = $_POST['ipd_no'];
    $token = "Empty";

    try{
        $dbh = getConnection();
        $flag = true;


        $sql = "SELECT ipd_reg_no 
                    FROM  ipd_bill 
                    WHERE ipd_reg_no = ?";
        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->bindParam(1,$ipd_no);
        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo $row;
        if($row >==0)
            $flag = false;
        if($flag)
            echo "success";
        else{
            $dbh->rollback();
            echo "fail";
        }
        //echo "\n FLAG: $flag \n";
        $dbh->commit(); 

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        print($e);
        try{
            $dbh->rollback();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            die($e->getMessage());  
        }
    }
    else{   //if ends here..
        echo "Outside if...";
}
```

Comment: I say read little more about AJAX calls AND you can return all the php params as JSON if you write dataType:"JSON". an also thing you should read about it how to use the json_encode()

Comment: And what is your problem? What's the question?

Comment: what is your problem??

Comment: suppose in my table there is no ipd_reg_no from that I want to exit

Comment: @Fazovsky success also show record Record could not be updated! message

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript code you have provided the `ipdNo` as the AJAX parameter, but in the PHP file you try to access an undefined key named `ipd_no` through `$_POST`. I also recommend to change the AJAX `dataType` from `"html"` to the `"text"`, because you are just echoing some plain text in the PHP file.

In the PHP file, in order to use the `PDO::commit` or `PDO::rollBack`, you need to first invoke `PDO::beginTransaction`.

Before calling `PDOStatement::fetch`, you need to execute your statement through `PDOStatement::execute`.

In the `if` statement you need to change the syntactically wrong statement of `$row >==0` to something like `$row!==false && count($row)>0`. Finally, consider that you don't have any matching `if` statement for you last `else` statement, where you commented `//if ends here..`, However; It just maybe not visible in you code snippet.

In addition, you are better to always check the returning result from any method call or function invoke.